# How to resolve the error: Cannot implicitly convert type `long' to `bool'?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
    
namespace Problem
{
    class Prog
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            long t= long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
         
            while (t-->0)
            {
                long n, even = 0, odd = 0, a;
    
                n = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    
                for (long i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    a = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (a % 2)
                        odd++;
                    else
                        even++;
                }
                Console.WriteLine((even < odd) ? even : odd);
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was using this code to solve a problem in hackerearth since am new to C#, so practicing, but I am not getting actually how to resolve this error saying:

> solution.cs(21,25): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'long' to 'bool'
> Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings`

Comment: Why just not to use `Convert.ToBoolean(...)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if` statements expect `bool` check, in your case `a % 2` returns just a `long` number because `a` is of type `long`.

You just need to write a `boolean expression` in your `if` statement.

```
if (a % 2 != 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for this help! I got the answer

Answer (score -1):

Usually when the  error message says

> Cannot  implicitly convert X to bool

It usually means it expects a boolean expression, so you should check the code where you have `if` statements and loops and check if you typed something wrong. Those are the places the compiler usually expects boolean expressions.

In your coding `if (a % 2)` is wrong, do note `a % 2` does return a long number, not a true/false value.

Comment: Thanks for the advice i'll surely use it from now onwards

Comment: Actually `while (t-->0)` is not wrong, it means `while ((t--)>0)`